# Android "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

after I install the ADT and add the CDT and NDK and add the OpenCV library 
this error appears

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing     ****

C:\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd 
jni/Android.mk:5: ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

this is the Android.mk code

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 10):

Change the `Android.mk` so that include refers to absolute path of OpenCV.mk. Ex:

```
WIN: include d:\dev\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk
Linux: include ~/mydevdir/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Comment: but my OpenCV-2.4.9 folder not contains sdk folder. What I should do? make a build with cmake?

Comment: @AmonOlimov you are looking in OpenCV project that's not the sdk. you need to download sdk and find into it [Direct downlod link sdk](http://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-android/2.4.9/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't in the location it expects.  It's expecting the `OpenCV.mk` file to exist in the directory `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCv.mk`

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fact that when using include, relative path starts from your project directory, not project/jni directory. Make sure your directory structure is like below,

- Root

  -- sdk

  -- Project

and your include line as:

```
include ../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```